# Finding the missing dates between two date ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table like

```
ID      StartDate                EndDate   
AAA     2017-03-17 00:00:00.000  2017-03-19 00:00:00.000  
BB      2017-06-20 00:00:00.000  2017-06-25 00:00:00.000    
CC      2017-05-13 00:00:00.000  2017-05-17 00:00:00.000  
DD      2017-06-20 00:00:00.000  2017-05-27 00:00:00.000  
EE      2017-03-01 00:00:00.000  2017-03-05 00:00:00.000  
FF      2017-08-07 00:00:00.000  2017-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

i need the missing dates in between these ranges and the output table should be like

```
ID    Date  
AAA   2017-03-17 00:00:00.000  -- Start date for AAA   
AAA   2017-03-18 00:00:00.000  
AAA   2017-03-19 00:00:00.000  -- End date for AAA  
BB    2017-06-20 00:00:00.000  -- start date for BB  
BB    2017-06-21 00:00:00.000  
BB    2017-06-22 00:00:00.000  
BB    2017-06-23 00:00:00.000  
BB    2017-06-24 00:00:00.000  
BB    2017-06-25 00:00:00.000  -- End date for BB
```

Comment: If they all start at midnight, why bother storing the time component at all? That said, this is a job for application code

Comment: 1. Mysql and ms sql server are two different products with different sql implementations. Which one do you use? 2. Questions are usually not well received here on SO if they do not contain any honest attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Time does not matter here. this is like leave database for where an employee takes leave from the start Date to the end date.So i need the missing dates in between @Strawberry

Comment: My bad,Sqlserver pls @Shadow

Comment: So store dates, not datetimes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add loop to get dates between start and end dates , Example :

```
         DECLARE  @table table (ID Varchar(50), StartDate datetime,EndDate datetime)

            insert into @table values ('AAA','2017-03-17 00:00:00.000',' 2017-03-19 00:00:00.000')
            insert into @table values ('BB','2017-06-20 00:00:00.000 ',' 2017-06-25 00:00:00.000')
            insert into @table values ('CC','2017-05-13 00:00:00.000 ',' 2017-05-17 00:00:00.000')
            insert into @table values ('DD','2017-06-20 00:00:00.000 ',' 2017-05-27 00:00:00.000')
            insert into @table values ('EE','2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 ',' 2017-03-05 00:00:00.000')
            insert into @table values ('FF','2017-08-07 00:00:00.000 ',' 2017-08-11 00:00:00.000')


            SELECT * FROM @table

            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='AAA'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='AAA'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='AAA'  
            union all 

            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='BB'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='BB'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='BB'  
            union all 

            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='CC'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='CC'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='CC'  
            union all 

            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='DD'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='DD'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='DD'  
            union all 


            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='EE'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='EE'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='EE'  
            union all 


            SELECT id, StartDate FROM @table WHERE id='FF'  
            union all 
            SELECT id, Dateadd(day,1,startdate) AS date FROM @table WHERE id='FF'  AND Dateadd(day,1,startdate)<EndDate
            union all 
            SELECT id, EndDate FROM @table WHERE id='FF'  

        Output:
             id StartDate
            AAA 2017-03-17 00:00:00.000
            AAA 2017-03-18 00:00:00.000
            AAA 2017-03-19 00:00:00.000
            BB  2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
            BB  2017-06-21 00:00:00.000
            BB  2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
            CC  2017-05-13 00:00:00.000
            CC  2017-05-14 00:00:00.000
            CC  2017-05-17 00:00:00.000
            DD  2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
            DD  2017-05-27 00:00:00.000
            EE  2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
            EE  2017-03-02 00:00:00.000
            EE  2017-03-05 00:00:00.000
            FF  2017-08-07 00:00:00.000
            FF  2017-08-08 00:00:00.000
            FF  2017-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i created a calendar table based on your MIN and MAX date to get all the dates involved. Then i joined it to your table.

```
DECLARE @calendar AS TABLE ([Date] DATETIME)

DECLARE @maxDate AS DATETIME = (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(StartDate) > MAX(EndDate) 
                                        THEN MAX(StartDate) 
                                        ELSE MAX(EndDate) 
                                   END FROM @YourTable)

DECLARE @minDate AS DATETIME = (SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(StartDate) < MIN(EndDate) 
                                        THEN MIN(StartDate)
                                        ELSE MIN(EndDate) 
                                    END FROM @YourTable)

WHILE (@minDate < @maxDate)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @calendar 
    VALUES (@minDate)
    SET @minDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @minDate)
END

SELECT [Id], a.[Date]
FROM (Select [Date] FROM @calendar) a
LEFT JOIN @YourTable ON [Date] BETWEEN [StartDate] AND [EndDate]
WHERE [Id] IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE t
    (
      ID NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
      StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL ,
      EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    );
    GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.t
        ( ID, StartDate, EndDate )
VALUES  ( N'AAA', '2017-03-17 00:00:00.000', '2017-03-19 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( N'BB', '2017-06-20 00:00:00.000', '2017-06-25 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( N'CC', '2017-05-13 00:00:00.000', '2017-05-17 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( N'DD', '2017-06-20 00:00:00.000', '2017-05-27 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( N'EE', '2017-03-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-03-05 00:00:00.000' ),
        ( N'FF', '2017-08-07 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 00:00:00.000' );



WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                        StartDate
               FROM     dbo.t
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.ID ,
                        DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte.StartDate)
               FROM     cte
                        INNER JOIN dbo.t ON t.ID = cte.ID
               WHERE    cte.StartDate < EndDate
             )
    SELECT  cte.ID ,
            cte.StartDate
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY cte.ID ,
            cte.StartDate;
```

Result:

```
ID    StartDate
----- -----------------------
AAA   2017-03-17 00:00:00.000
AAA   2017-03-18 00:00:00.000
AAA   2017-03-19 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-21 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-22 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-23 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-24 00:00:00.000
BB    2017-06-25 00:00:00.000
CC    2017-05-13 00:00:00.000
CC    2017-05-14 00:00:00.000
CC    2017-05-15 00:00:00.000
CC    2017-05-16 00:00:00.000
CC    2017-05-17 00:00:00.000
DD    2017-06-20 00:00:00.000
EE    2017-03-01 00:00:00.000
EE    2017-03-02 00:00:00.000
EE    2017-03-03 00:00:00.000
EE    2017-03-04 00:00:00.000
EE    2017-03-05 00:00:00.000
FF    2017-08-07 00:00:00.000
FF    2017-08-08 00:00:00.000
FF    2017-08-09 00:00:00.000
FF    2017-08-10 00:00:00.000
FF    2017-08-11 00:00:00.000
```